# Standard Widgets are not working

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I have a `hook_menu` in my module.

`Artwork` is a content type.

```
$items['galleryguide/artwork/new'] = array(
  'title' => t('Add new Artwork'),
  'page callback' => 'galleryguide_admin_artwork_new',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'file' => 'galleryguide_admin.artwork.inc'
);
```

And I have hook_theme

```
function galleryguide_admin_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'artwork_form' => array(
      'template' => 'artwork_form',
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

In .inc I do:

```
function galleryguide_admin_artwork_new() {
  return drupal_get_form('galleryguide_admin_artwork_form_new');
}

function galleryguide_admin_artwork_form_new() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('artwork');
  $form['#theme'] = array('artwork_form');
  return $form;
}
```

Then in my template, `artwork_form.tpl.php`, I put

```
print drupal_render_children($form);
```

Everything renders fine, but I have an image upload file field and it does not work. It selects an image and then after I press upload it does not show any prevew and does not upload image
If I try to add node reference field I see system/ajax 500 error and nothing on frontend.

Same with all cck with widgets

Also file upload adds ajax-new-content span with empty inner html

Using same theme, and admin.

Can anyone tell me what can be the reason of that?

Comment: You need to check the webserver logs for that error 500, we can't divine it for you. :)

Comment: But what about file field wich uploads images? It does not send any post when I click upload.